# Confusion about Go debug by GDB

Tags: debugging, go, gdb

I'm a java programer and I'm learning Go. Now I can use GDB simply and I have a doubt, when I debugging a Go program ,I can't check an object(or variable) what it exactly is.
e.g. when I debug a java program,I can check everything in an object(or variable).

```
    public void catTest() {
      Cat cat1=new Cat("Kitty", 2, "white");
      /*AnyThing*/
      cat1.jump();
    }
```

When I debug this java method using eclipse-debug mode,what in cat1 are obviously in the whole process. 
[Details of Variable cat1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxZB6.png)

When I debug a go program,I try to check variable w by using command `print w` or `info args`.

```
    func sayhelloName(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    r.ParseForm()    
    fmt.Println(r.Form)  
    fmt.Println("path", r.URL.Path)    
    fmt.Println("scheme", r.URL.Scheme)    
    fmt.Println(r.Form["url_long"])    
    for k, v := range r.Form {
        fmt.Println("key:", k)        
        fmt.Println("val:", strings.Join(v, ""))    
    }    
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello astaxie!")
}
```

I can just get this but not what inside about variable w.

```
$2 = {tab = 0x81c2e0, data = 0x11156990}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what happens when you try `print w.data`

Comment: That is what is inside the variable `w`. GDB requires some low level knowledge of Go, and can't handle all parts of the runtime. I would start with [delve](https://github.com/derekparker/delve/) rather than gdb.

Comment: @Gab print w.data is also displaying an address.It seems like can’t check what insider is.

Comment: can you try `print *(w.data)`? I have only used gdb for C, so i'm just trying to see if that works

Comment: @JimB Thanks.Could delve achieve my requirement?

Comment: @Gab It doesn’t work and hit “Attempt to dereference a generic pointer”,but print *(w.tab) goes well.So messy.How do you check a complex object(or variable or struct) when debugging by GDB?

Comment: When it comes to C, you access the data the same way you would in your program. So if you have `char *sentence`, you could access the first letter like this: `print *sentence` or `print sentence[0]`. I would imagine that the same applies to Go (but obviously not using Go syntax)

Comment: @Gab Thanks, it seems not so convenient for some multilevel-complex object 

Comment: http.ResponseWriter is an interface. What concrete type did you use for it in this particular call?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Of cause it’s an interface.And w is a variable which implemented this interface,I’d like to check inner of w .In java, when debugging, I can check a variable in detail even I didn’t know the struct of this variable.

Comment: I asked what concrete type is used so that I can check whether `{tab = 0x81c2e0, data = 0x11156990}` is the correct struct or not.

Comment: @Mark Plotnick Using command 'whatis w' could get this 'type = net/http.ResponseWriter'

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I’m using delve,it is working well.